# How to prevent React Native keyboard pushing absolute views

Tags: react-native

Im trying to keep the absolute two buttons behind the keyboard, becuase in smaller screens the buttons will appear above the input field. how can i do that?

[image]

i need the absolute buttons to be under the keyboard when its open

Comment: Please, add a code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adjusting properties of android:windowSoftInputMode under

`android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

In my case, buttons get underneath the keyboard by setting

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

To get more information about this go with the below link I've attached

[Handle Input Method Visibility](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/visibility)